# how do i make automatically changing quiz in HTML (jquery maybe?)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

sorry my title is absolutely horrible because i can't think of how to explain this.

basically, i have a certain DIV that i want to put a little minature "quiz" inside. it's a quiz that will ask stuff like, so how old are you? with answers, im age 20-30, 30-40, 40-50, etc. it will be random questions like this. but i want it to be like, when they click an answer, it will automatically goto the next question and ask them the next question where they put in the next answer.

i want to have it like 5 questions, then have the whole webpage go to a new page after that.

would this be jquery? i have seen people do this type of thing with cell phone type quizes in jquery, but i have no idea what it is even called in HTML or what to even search for on google for.

if someone could just point me in the direction to go, you don't have to code the whole thing out for me, but somewhere to start and what to do.

Comment: You need _Asynchronous form submission using JQuery, Ajax and PHP_ (or whatever server side language you have)

Comment: @Asif Not necessarily... You could just do one big form-submission at the end.

Comment: @ahren I follow the words "_when they click an answer, it will automatically goto the next question_"

Comment: Could hide the containing `div`, or store the data client-side and send it all at the end. What's the use of potentially having a partially-filled database?

Comment: i dont even care about the data to be honest.. i just want a form for people to go through

Comment: they just cilck through questions, and whatever ansers they give it doesnt matter, it always brings them to the same place

Answer (score 2):

JQuery /JS Can solve it.

You Must bind event on answer elements,

When They click element,it will trigger a function,

in this function, you can  add ,delete,modify elements in your page as you want.

jquery has any api that you want .

Comment: okay i will look into jquery. do you have any idea hwere i can find tutorials on this type of thing to do this?

Comment: sorry,I haven't. use jquery $('div') to create a element.then you can append html  ,bind event etc..

Answer (score 1):

jQuery is a simple JavaScript library. it could help to manipulate the page content ( DOM structure  of page ).you can add , delete , modify elements in your page as you want  so yes i think jQuery may fit.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this little quiz [script](http://www.fatihacet.com/lab/jQuiz/) that user [Faith](https://stackoverflow.com/users/480949/fatih) made in response to this stackoverflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4464406/creating-a-quiz-with-jquery). It uses jQuery, CSS, and HTML.

[HTML Source](http://pastebin.com/vByWz1tE)

[JS Source](http://pastebin.com/QRjiY6KD)

[CSS Source](http://pastebin.com/k38xJb3B)